# How to normalize the following dates inside a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the following [dates](http://pastebin.com/QxvZET8T) dataframe:

```
   dates
0  2012 10 4
1
2  2012 01 19
3  20 6 11
4  20 10 7
5  19 11 12
6
7  2013 03 19
8  2016 2 5
9  2011 2 19
10
11  2011 05 23
12  2012 04 5
```

How can I normalize the dates column into:

```
     dates
0  2012 10 04
1
2  2012 01 19
3  2020 06 11
4  2020 10 07
5  2019 11 12
6
7  2013 03 19
8  2016 02 05
9 2011 02 19
10
11 2011 05 23
12 2012 04 05
```

I tried with regex and splitting and tweaking each column separately. However I am complicating the task. Is it possible to normalize this into the latter dataframe?. The rule is to add a `0` if the year is incomplete or a `20` at the beggining of the string if the year is incomplete, the format is `yyyymmdd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
x = (df.loc[df.dates.str.contains(r'\d+\s*\d+\s*\d+'), 'dates']
       .str.split(expand=True)
       .rename(columns={0:'year',1:'month',2:'day'})
       .astype(int)
)
x.loc[x.year <= 50, 'year'] += 2000
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Result:

```
In [148]: df
Out[148]:
         dates       new
0    2012 10 4  20121004
1                    NaN
2   2012 01 19  20120119
3      20 6 11  20200611
4      20 10 7  20201007
5     19 11 12  20191112
6                    NaN
7   2013 03 19  20130319
8     2016 2 5  20160205
9    2011 2 19  20110219
10                   NaN
11  2011 05 23  20110523
12   2012 04 5  20120405
```

Explanation:

```
In [149]: df.loc[df.dates.str.contains(r'\d+\s*\d+\s*\d+'), 'dates']
Out[149]:
0      2012 10 4
2     2012 01 19
3        20 6 11
4        20 10 7
5       19 11 12
7     2013 03 19
8       2016 2 5
9      2011 2 19
11    2011 05 23
12     2012 04 5
Name: dates, dtype: object

In [152]: (df.loc[df.dates.str.contains(r'\d+\s*\d+\s*\d+'), 'dates']
     ...:    .str.split(expand=True)
     ...:    .rename(columns={0:'year',1:'month',2:'day'})
     ...:    .astype(int))
Out[152]:
    year  month  day
0   2012     10    4
2   2012      1   19
3     20      6   11
4     20     10    7
5     19     11   12
7   2013      3   19
8   2016      2    5
9   2011      2   19
11  2011      5   23
12  2012      4    5
```

Comment: Huh... again I got: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: Huh.... again: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '09T'`

Comment: Huh, again, provide a __REPRODUCIBLE__ data set ;)

Comment: I copied and pasted some data... basically is the same but shorter

Comment: Huh, In your "shorter" version there was no "numbers" like `'09T'`

Comment: Hint: first clean up your data: `df.dates = df.dates.str.replace(r'\D+', ' ')` then use a solution from my answer...

Comment: It seems that some values had letters.... after apply the last regex this was solved.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @tumbleweed, you are welcome. Please provide a reproducible data sets next time - this will save your and our time dramatically